# jQuery getSelection of already colour highlighted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, getselection

I found a jQuery plugin that allows me to highlight my text with a color which works perfectly. But now I need to get the highlighted text selection and place it in a text box.

I found this code which is exactly what I'm looking for although it doesn't pick up my color highlight as a selection.

This is the code I found and want to use is at this link http://www.codetoad.com/javascript_get_selected_text.asp#highlight2

Comment: I assume the jQuery plugin only wraps the text in an element like `<span style="background:yellow">`. This is not the same as selecting characters with the mouse. Which highlighting plugin do you use?

Comment: the plugin i found at this link http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-text-highlighter-plugins/ it is number 6 on the list

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the plugin "only" wraps text in a span. To access that text, you can use standard jQuery selectors. Basically, it works like this:

```
// the plugin generates new <span> elements with class="highlighted".
// You fetch all those with $('.highlighted.'). Then you get their text
// content by calling .text() [1]:
var text = $('.highlighted').text();

// Access your <textarea>, where you want to put the text into. Either
// use an ID element and use $('#id-of-textarea'), class or other means.
// to get the 1st one, use the ':eq(0)' jQuery selector (':eq(1)' for the
// second and so on) [2]. Then set the text with the jQuery .val() call [3]:
$('textarea:eq(0)'.val(text);
```

In your question you link to `getSelection()` method and its relatives. Those are good, if you want to access text selected by the user via mouse.

[1] http://api.jquery.com/text/

[2] http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

[3] http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Please im new to this so i am a bit confused is it possible that you can give me a working example. I appreciate your help thank you

Comment: @zaakirah "Working example" depends highly on what you need to do concretely. But I extended the comments a bit. Hopefully it becomes clearer what I meant.